# Entity Framework Core Navigation Properties Error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a simple app to try Entity Framework Core, but i a have problem with setting up relations between entities. My entities:

```
public class Card
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoS { get; set; }
    public User Portal { get; set; }
    public List<Reservation> Res { get; set; }
}
public class Doctor
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Start_Working { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan End_Working { get; set; }
    public List<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public int SpecID { get; set; }
    public Spec Spec { get; set; }
}
public class Reservation
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoR { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public int CardID { get; set; }
    public Card Card_Nav_R { get; set; }
    public int DoctorID { get; set; }
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}
public class Spec
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int CardID { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
}
```

And a configuration class where i tried to set up relations:

```
class ApplicationContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Spec> Specs { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder ModelBuilder)
    {
          ModelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.Id);
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Card>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().HasKey(d => d.Id);
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Spec>().HasKey(s => s.Id);
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>().HasKey(r => r.Id);

          ModelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Password).IsRequired();

          ModelBuilder.Entity<Card>().Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Card>().Property(c => c.Surname).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Card>().Property(c => c.DoB).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Card>().Property(c => c.Adress).IsRequired();

          ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().Property(d => d.Name).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().Property(d => d.Surname).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().Property(d => d.Spec).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().Property(d => d.Email).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().Property(d => d.Start_Working).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().Property(d => d.End_Working).IsRequired();

          ModelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>().Property(r => r.Info).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>().Property(r => r.Card_Nav_R).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>().Property(r => r.Doctor).IsRequired();
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>().Property(r => r.DoR).IsRequired();

        ModelBuilder.Entity<Spec>().Property(s => s.Name).IsRequired();

          ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().HasOne<Spec>(d=>d.Spec).WithMany(s => s.Doctors).HasForeignKey(d => d.SpecID);
          ModelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne<Card>(u => u.Card).WithOne(c => c.Portal).HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.CardID);
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>().HasOne<Card>(r => r.Card_Nav_R).WithMany(c => c.Res).HasForeignKey(r => r.CardID);
          ModelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>().HasOne<Doctor>(r => r.Doctor).WithMany(d => d.Reservations).HasForeignKey(r => r.DoctorID); 

    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Simple_Try;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```

So, when i tried to add migration or add something to database i saw this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property or navigation 'Spec' cannot be added to the entity type 'Doctor' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'Doctor'.'

I really don't know how to fix this, i tried to use annotations instead of Fluent API, but had the same result.

Comment: UPDATE: Even without trying to set up foreign keys with Fluent API i have another error on `Database.EnsureCreated();`
'System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Doctor.Spec' is of type 'Spec' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.''

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of the exception is the following line:

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().Property(d => d.Spec).IsRequired();
```

because `Doctor.Spec` is a navigation property

```
public class Doctor
{
    // ...
    public Spec Spec { get; set; }
}
```

and navigation properties cannot be configured via `Property` fluent API.

So simply remove that line. Whether reference navigation property is  required or optional is controlled via relationship configuration. In this case

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>()
   .HasOne(d => d.Spec)
   .WithMany(s => s.Doctors)
   .HasForeignKey(d => d.SpecID)
   .IsRequired(); // <--
```

although the `IsRequired` is automatically derived from the FK property type - since `SpecID` is non nullable, then the relationship is required.

For more info, see [Required and Optional Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional) and [Required and Optional Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships) documentation topics.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works!
So, except this mistake with navigation property everything else seems allright?

Comment: Haven't checked it carefully. But if you have other issues, you can always ask :) I would personally skip all the fluent configuration which is conventional - for instance all `HasKey`, all `IsRequired` for `int`, `TimeSpan` (i.e. non nullbale types) etc.